# JW Player - How to genrate RSS of video playlist in wordpress

Tags: rss, video-player, jwplayer

I am planning to use JW player in wordpress.

If it is a single video it works fine. For playlist JW is expecting .rss file.

How can i generate video playlist rss in worpress ?

I saw some built in feed for post . Is there any way to re use that ?

Is there any alternative way to show playlist in JW Player?

Comment: This is a border line question as we can't help you figure what the JW can or can not do and what are its parameters. If you want an helpful answer you need to provide the information of what exactly you need to generate in wordpress to integrate with JW.

Comment: Thanks for that quick response.Can i generate custom rss  in wordpress?